Dynamic Array - How to Conditionally Generate Sums?
I have a formula that's meant to iterate through a dynamic range, generate cumulative rows (the #/# in "Tally" represents a number of pieces and a length in ft.) and stack them into a new sheet.
Data being processed comes in this format:



po_number
po_line_item
sku
container
tally
rp




12345
54321
PNE16s
24680
5/8, 10/16
2



Data is currently processed by the formula (below) into this format:



recieved_qty
po_number
po_item
stock_code
container_id
rec_process




200
12345
54321
PNE16s
24680
2


40
12345
54321
PNE16s.8
24680
2


160
12345
54321
PNE16s.16
24680
2



I am trying to slightly alter the way that received_qty is calculated, as below:



recieved_qty
po_number
po_item
stock_code
container_id
rec_process




200
12345
54321
PNE16s
24680
2


5
12345
54321
PNE16s.8
24680
2


10
12345
54321
PNE16s.16
24680
2



And am struggling with how I need to alter the cumulative row generation to accommodate this. I know that basically I need IF(qty = 0, return qty * len, ELSE return qty but I'm not actually sure how to pipe that in. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated! The "po_info" is an index of another sheet that will house this raw data less the header rows, since I just define them in the formula below.
=LET(
    data, po_info,
    row_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
    result, REDUCE(
        TEXTSPLIT("RECEIVED_QTY,PO_NUMBER,PO_ITEM,STOCK_CODE,CONTAINER_ID,REC_PROCESS", ","),
        row_indices,
        LAMBDA(acc_res,cur_row,
            LET(
                PO_NUMBER, INDEX(data, cur_row, 1),
                PO_ITEM, INDEX(data, cur_row, 2),
                STOCK_CODE, INDEX(data, cur_row, 3),
                CONTAINER_ID, INDEX(data, cur_row, 4),
                REC_PROCESS, INDEX(data, cur_row, 5),
                tally, INDEX(data, cur_row, 6),
                qty_lengths, TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(tally), ","),
                result_0, REDUCE(
                    "cumulative_row",
                    qty_lengths,
                    LAMBDA(acc,cur,
                        LET(
                            qty_len, TEXTSPLIT(cur, "/"),
                            qty, INDEX(qty_len, , 1),
                            len, INDEX(qty_len, , 2),
                            row_, HSTACK(
                                qty * len,
                                PO_NUMBER,
                                PO_ITEM,
                                CONCAT(STOCK_CODE, ".", len),
                                "" & CONTAINER_ID,
                                REC_PROCESS
                            ),
                            VSTACK(acc, row_)
                        )
                    )
                ),
                cumulative_row, HSTACK(
                    SUM(INDEX(result_0, , 1)),
                    PO_NUMBER,
                    PO_ITEM,
                    STOCK_CODE,
                    CONCAT(CONTAINER_ID,),
                    REC_PROCESS
                ),
                result, VSTACK(cumulative_row, DROP(result_0, 1)),
                VSTACK(acc_res, result)
            )
        )
    ),
    result
)


Also not sure why the first and second tables are breaking since they're fine in the preview.. working on them now.. thanks in advance again!

the tables where correct , but you need a blank line in between your text and the table for it to be displayed correctly. Somehow the preview shows it without any problems though, but the end post doesn't allow it that way.

If efficiency is a concern, it's best to avoid iterative methods like REDUCE with INDEX and VSTACK, as they tend to perform very poorly when the number of iterations exceeds 1,000.
As an alternative, consider the following approach:
=LET(
    data, po_info,
    rowId, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
    tally, CHOOSECOLS(data, 5),
    total_received, MAP(tally, LAMBDA(v, LET(a, TEXTSPLIT(v, "/", ","), SUM(TAKE(a,, 1) * DROP(a,, 1))))),
    total_rows, HSTACK(total_received, CHOOSECOLS(data, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6)),
    tally_count, LEN(tally) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(tally, ",", )) + 1,
    tally_cols, SEQUENCE(, MAX(tally_count)),
    tallys, TOCOL(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER("," & tally & ",", ",", tally_cols), ","), 2),
    rowIds, TOCOL(IFS(tally_count >= tally_cols, rowId), 2),
    data_array, CHOOSEROWS(data, rowIds),
    stock_code, CHOOSECOLS(data_array, 3) & "." & TEXTAFTER(tallys, "/"),
    qty_received, --TEXTBEFORE(tallys, "/"),
    qty_rows, CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(qty_received, data_array, stock_code), 1, 2, 3, 8, 5, 7),
    VSTACK(
        {"RECIEVED_QTY","PO_NUMBER","PO_ITEM","STOCK_CODE","CONTAINER_ID","REC_PROCESS"},
        SORTBY(VSTACK(total_rows, qty_rows), VSTACK(rowId, rowIds))
    )
)

NOTE: the sample table you shared seems to indicate that "tally" is column 5, but the formula you shared defines tally as column 6. Please adjust the column numbers as needed.
The total rows are produced first. This is done by calculating the total received for each record using MAP, appending the results to the original dataset using HSTACK, and removing the original tally column using CHOOSECOLS.
Next, the tally column is split into an array using TEXTBEFORE & TEXTAFTER. The width of the array is determined by the record containing the greatest number of "," delimiters. Any records with fewer delimiters than the maximum will be filled with #N/A in their excess columns. TOCOL is then used to send the results to a single column with the errors removed (by setting the optional [ignore] argument to 2).
The TOCOL & IFS method is then used to repeat the row numbers of the original dataset accordingly, which in turn are used to pull the appropriate records using CHOOSEROWS. The resulting data array is then manipulated using CHOOSECOLS, TEXTAFTER, TEXTBEFORE and HSTACK to produce the desired output for the rows containing the individual quantities.
Lastly, the quantity rows are appended below the total rows and sorted by row number using VSTACK and SORTBY. VSTACK is also used to add the headers to the final output.
To compare: when tested with 5,000 rows of data, this method returned the results in a split second, whereas REDUCE with INDEX and VSTACK took approx. 20 seconds.


=LET(range,A2:F3,
REDUCE({"recieved_qty","po_number","po_item","stock_code","container_id","rec_process"},
       SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),
LAMBDA(a,b,
       LET(c,--TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(range,b,5),"/",","), 
       VSTACK(a,
              IFNA(HSTACK(
                          VSTACK(SUM(TAKE(c,,1)*DROP(c,,1)),
                                 TAKE(c,,1)),
                          INDEX(range,b,{1,2}),
                          INDEX(range,b,3)&VSTACK("","."&DROP(c,,1)),
                          INDEX(range,b,{4,6})),
                   INDEX(range,b,{0,1,2,3,4,6})))))))

c will split your tally values in two columns that you can multiply and use the first column to (v)stack underneath the multiplication.
Next (h)stack the column values of referenced row. Since that's a single line array and the vstacked tally calculation is multiple lines, this creates a spill range including #N/A. This is where we make use of IFNA to lift along the indexed values.

